# Microphone volume randomly reduced

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, microphone, volume

I have a Lenovo A6000 phone, Android 4.4.4 is installed. I have Dolby off and I don't use any app to control volumes (not even skype, viber or facebook messenger), also, the phone is NOT rooted.

Sometimes the microphone's recording volume becomes so low, others can hardly hear me talking. It happens randomly and If I restart the phone, the volume becomes correct again.

I can always test If It is correct or not, because I have a similar sound recording software preinstalled on my device like this:

[image]

And I can use the sound sensitivity meter to see if it is high enough, sometimes it becomes so low that I cannot get it higher than 10% when I am talking normally.

I guess It is not a hardware issue, because a restart solves it instantly. Is there any app that can interfere with the microphone volume?

Edit.: Some people say that If I update to Lolipop it solves the issue, but I don't have any software updates available.